# Why is trim not working?

Tags: java

The String content is something like this:

```
 <div ...>
    <ul ...>

        <li ...><a href="...">...</a></li>

        ...

    </ul>

</div>
```

with `str.trim().split("\n");` the result ist something like `[<div ...>,     <ul ...>,      <li ...]`

So it did not really trimed the String ?!

I have bypassed this, with iterating over the result of `str.split("\n")` and trimming every single String (line) in the result Array.

Even if it is now working, I did not understand, why it was not before (trimming whole String) ?

Has anybody a clue ?

Comment: Remember that Strings are immutable in Java, you should assign the result to a *new* String.

Comment: trim only works on the start and end of the String, it won't remove whitespace somewhere halfway in it. As documented. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29

Comment: So is the only solution for it, like i did to "bypass" this :)

Comment: Of course not, you can just use the replace() methods :/

Comment: I understood this function wrong, I thought it would trim any whitespace or tab within the string.

Answer (score 1):

[As said in the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29), `String.split()` doesn't remove the whitespaces at the beginning/end of each line, but at the beginning/end of the whole `String`:

> Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted.
>   [...]
>   This method may be used to trim whitespace (as defined above) from the beginning and end of a string.

To do that, you can:

- `split()` the `String` and call `trim()` on each part, just as you have done
- use a regexp to implement a "multi-lines trim":

  ```
  str = str.replaceAll("(?m)(^[\u0000-\u0020]+|[\u0000-\u0020]+$)", "");
  ```

  - the `(?m)` flag tells Java to accept the anchors `^` and `$` to match at the start and end of each line
  - `[\u0000-\u0020]` means every character from 0 to 20 (what is defined as being a whitespace by the `trim()` javadoc.

If you want to remove all the whitespace in the `String` (even if they are not at the beginning/end of line), you can also do that with a regexp (this will also remove the newlines as they are considered as spaces):

```
str = str.replaceAll("[\u0000-\u0020]+", "");
```

or

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case `str.trim().split("\n");` you first trim the whole string and than split the string at the end of line. In second case you first split the line and then trim every line.

Answer (score 0):

You're trimming the whole thing, then splitting. What you need is to first split, then trim each of the individual lines:

```
String[] lines = str.split("\n");
for (int i=0; i<lines.length(); i++)
   lines[i] = lines[i].trim();
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't understand how trim works. Here is the JavaDoc for `java.lang.String trim()` function

Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted.

If this String object represents an empty character sequence, or the first and last characters of character sequence represented by this String object both have codes greater than '\u0020' (the space character), then a reference to this String object is returned.

Otherwise, if there is no character with a code greater than '\u0020' in the string, then a new String object representing an empty string is created and returned.

Otherwise, let k be the index of the first character in the string whose code is greater than '\u0020', and let m be the index of the last character in the string whose code is greater than '\u0020'.

A new String object is created, representing the substring of this string that begins with the character at index k and ends with the character at index m-that is, the result of this.substring(k, m+1).

This method may be used to trim whitespace (as defined above) from the beginning and end of a string.

**Returns:**
A copy of this string with leading and trailing white space removed, or this string if it has no leading or trailing white space.